# jQuery Validation of File Upload Fields on Edit

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a file upload field in a form using jQuery Validation Plugin.  I only need to check if the file was uploaded, not if the file was a certain size and/or type.  Everything works fine on the original submission, the issue is the form is submitted to a database and allowed to be edited later.  When editing the form I have setup an additional hidden field with `_orig` appended to the end.  So for a field called `check_upload` there is a field called `check_upload_orig` which will contain the previous submission data.  That way a user does not have to re-upload a file each time.  So I am not sure how to write a method to check if the 'check_upload_orig' field has a value when the `check_upload` field is empty. There are multiple file upload fields in this particular form. Some are required and some are not. Any suggestions?

Here is the code on a new form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#modify").validate({
            onkeyup: function(element){ $(element).valid(); },
            onfocusout: function(element){ $(element).valid(); },
            rules: {
            },
            highlight: function(element, errorClass, validclass) {
                // if the element is a checkbox, highlight the entire group
                if(element.type=='checkbox') {
                    $(element).parent('.ctrlHolder').addClass('error');
                } else {
                    $(element).addClass('error');
                }
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validclass) {
                if(element.type=='checkbox') {
                    $(element).parent('.ctrlHolder').removeClass('error');
                } else {
                    $(element).removeClass('error');
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    }); // end $(document).ready(function()
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="modify" name="modify" action="./" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="check_upload" name="check_upload" class=""  />
    <input type="hidden" id="check_upload_orig" name="check_upload_orig" value=""  />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the code for editing the form. The only difference is the `check_upload_orig field` contains a value from the previous submission. So if that value is set then the field should not be required to have a new file uploaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#modify").validate({
            onkeyup: function(element){ $(element).valid(); },
            onfocusout: function(element){ $(element).valid(); },
            rules: {
            },
            highlight: function(element, errorClass, validclass) {
                // if the element is a checkbox, highlight the entire group
                if(element.type=='checkbox') {
                    $(element).parent('.ctrlHolder').addClass('error');
                } else {
                    $(element).addClass('error');
                }
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validclass) {
                if(element.type=='checkbox') {
                    $(element).parent('.ctrlHolder').removeClass('error');
                } else {
                    $(element).removeClass('error');
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    }); // end $(document).ready(function()
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="modify" name="modify" action="./" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="check_upload" name="check_upload" class=""  />
    <input type="hidden" id="check_upload_orig" name="check_upload_orig" value="32.jpg"  />
    <input type="submit" name="view_fa_php_submit" id="view_fa_php_submit" class="submit view_fa_php_submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post some code snippets? It's hard to unterstand your problem.

Comment: Hopefully that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Your `rules` could look like:

```
rules: {
    check_upload: {
        required: '#check_upload_orig:blank'
    }
}
```

This means `check_upload` is just required, if `check_upload_orig` is blank. The `:blank`-pseudoselector is a custom selector of jQuery-Validation (see: http://jqueryvalidation.org/blank-selector/).

For more info on `required`-functions see http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/

I hope this helps you a bit

*the code is not tested*

Comment: Perfect, that helped point me in the correct direction.  Had not seen the :blank selector before, but that is quite useful!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final code I ended up using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#modify").validate({
            onkeyup: function(element){ $(element).valid(); },
            onfocusout: function(element){ $(element).valid(); },
            rules: {
                check_upload: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element) {
                            return $("#check_upload_orig").is(":blank");
                        }
                    },
                },
            },
            highlight: function(element, errorClass, validclass) {
                // if the element is a checkbox, highlight the entire group
                if(element.type=='checkbox') {
                    $(element).parent('.ctrlHolder').addClass('error');
                } else {
                    $(element).addClass('error');
                }
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validclass) {
                if(element.type=='checkbox') {
                    $(element).parent('.ctrlHolder').removeClass('error');
                } else {
                    $(element).removeClass('error');
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    }); // end $(document).ready(function()
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="modify" name="modify" action="./" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="check_upload" name="check_upload" class=""  />
    <input type="hidden" id="check_upload_orig" name="check_upload_orig" value="32.jpg"  />
    <input type="submit" name="view_fa_php_submit" id="view_fa_php_submit" class="submit view_fa_php_submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```